# Allow traffic from a webjob in a staging slot in Azure

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-webjobs, azure-deployment-slots

I'm using a staging slot in Azure, where I just allow some IP's to have access to it. I have written the below rule in the web.config file:

```
<rule name="Block unauthorized traffic to staging sites" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions>              
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain\-mydomainslot1\."/>
           <!-- white listed IP addresses -->
           <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="ip1" negate="true"/>
           <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="ip2" negate="true"/>        
         </conditions>
         <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden"
         statusDescription="Site is not accessible" />
       </rule>
```

The slot accepts traffic from my domain, ip1 and ip2. However, I have a webjob (which is in the slot) that makes a PostAsJsonAsync call the to the slot url, and I receive a forbidden as an answer. I don't know the IP address of the webjob (it is supposed to be the same as the website/slot), but anyway, I don't have a static IP address to use it in the rule. How should I solve this problem?  Is there another way of solving this issue without reserving an IP in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have figured out. Theres no need to reserve an IP. I have just added all the possible outbound IPs to my web.config and it's working now. I was missing the fact that the inbound and outbound IPs are different. The webjob has the same virtual IP as the website, but there can be multiple outbound IPs. [Those outbound IPs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) are in the Azure Portal.