# How to prevent a development staging website, hosted on Azure, from being indexed by search engines

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Specific to Web Apps hosted on `Microsoft Azure`, is there a way to prevent the `mydomain.azurewebsites.net` URL from being indexed by search engines? I'm planning to use a web app as a staging website, and don't want it to accidentally get indexed.

I know I could add a `robots.txt` file to the project with everything set to `no-index`, but I don't want to ever accidentally publish it to the production site (or alternatively, forget to publish it to the staging website).

Is there a setting in Azure that will prevent the ".azurewebsites.net" domain from being indexed? Or if the `robots.txt` file is the only way, how do you keep it organized so that the right `robots.txt` file is published to staging and production, using `ASP.NET Core`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to enable Authentication against your Azure Active Directory from the Authentication/Authorization tab in your App Service's settings for development and staging environments.

This way users will be forced to login to access those apps.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication

Comment: Thank you for the third option @Juunas. This was actually the easiest method to implement.

Comment: I found this article helpful as well setting it up, if you want to include it in your answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication

Answer (score 2):

You can publish robots.txt to your staging server once. This can be done via FTP or via your SCM site. Once you publish this file, web publish will not remove additional files on the server (including your robots.txt file) unless you select "Remove additional files at destination" in your web publish settings.

So the robots.txt file will hang around forever on your staging server unless you remove it. Then you do not need to include robots.txt in your project or solution, and not risk accidentally publishing it to your production environment.

Comment: This is a really good idea too! I will do this if the IP restriction method gives me issues. I wish I could mark both answers as correct.

Comment: Glad it helps. I generally take the approach that is simplest to implement with the fewest moving parts.

Answer (score 2):

#### Restrict access based on hostname and request IP

Unless you need your staging slot to be accessible to a wide range of dynamic IPs, you could consider using the [URL Rewrite module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) and adding rule[s] to your web app config to disallow traffic except for a few known IPs, but make those rules conditional on the HOST header matching the staging host (`mydomain.azurewebsites.net`), so they can never apply on the production hostname.

The [details in the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35999550/947986) show a similar type of setup.

Comment: I like it! This has the added benefit of restricting access to the staging website all together. Thanks @Dusty